# Json String conversion

Tags: ios

I have a json string. But i cannot change it to a Dictionary String:Any . Can anyone help me?

Here is my code

```
var str = "{\"01-2021\":\"[\"01 06 2021\",\"01 07 2021\",\"01 13 2021\",\"01 14 2021\",\"01 20 2021\",\"01 21 2021\",\"01 27 2021\",\"01 28 2021\"]\",\"02-2021\":\"[\"02 03 2021\",\"02 04 2021\",\"02 10 2021\",\"02 11 2021\",\"02 17 2021\",\"02 18 2021\",\"02 24 2021\",\"02 25 2021\"]\"}"

let data = string.data(using: .utf8)!


do {
    if let jsonArray = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options : .fragmentsAllowed) as? [String: Any]
    {
        print(jsonArray) // use the json here
    } else {
        print("bad json")
    }
} catch let error as NSError {
    print(error)
}
```

I always get error like this: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Badly formed object around character 14." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Badly formed object around character 14.}

Comment: I want to convert to Dictionary like ["01-2021" : "["01 06 2021","01 07 2021","01 13 2021","01 14 2021","01 20 2021","01 21 2021","01 27 2021","01 28 2021"]", [02-2021" : "["02 03 2021","02 04 2021","02 10 2021","02 11 2021","02 17 2021","02 18 2021","02 24 2021","02 25 2021"]"]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please read the error message and check what character 14 is? The (escaped) double quote after the first colon is the closing double quote of the (escaped) double quote before the colon. This is invalid syntax. Your JSON string is a corrupted `[String:String]` dictionary.

The literal string syntax makes it clearer

```
let str = """
{"01-2021":"["01 06 2021","01 07 2021","01 13 2021","01 14 2021","01 20 2021","01 21 2021","01 27 2021","01 28 2021"]","02-2021":"["02 03 2021","02 04 2021","02 10 2021","02 11 2021","02 17 2021","02 18 2021","02 24 2021","02 25 2021"]"}
"""
```

The opening square bracket `"["` is a string literal and the following `0` is invalid.

---

If you want `[String:String]` it's supposed to be

```
let str = """
{"01-2021":"[\\\"01 06 2021\\\",\\\"01 07 2021\\\",\\\"01 13 2021\\\",\\\"01 14 2021\\\",\\\"01 20 2021\\\",\\\"01 21 2021\\\",\\\"01 27 2021\\\",\\\"01 28 2021\\\"]","02-2021":"[\\\"02 03 2021\\\",\\\"02 04 2021\\\",\\\"02 10 2021\\\",\\\"02 11 2021\\\",\\\"02 17 2021\\\",\\\"02 18 2021\\\",\\\"02 24 2021\\\",\\\"02 25 2021\\\"]"}
"""
```

And if you want `[String:Any]` which is actually `[String:[String]]` it's

```
let str = """
{"01-2021":["01 06 2021","01 07 2021","01 13 2021","01 14 2021","01 20 2021","01 21 2021","01 27 2021","01 28 2021"],"02-2021":["02 03 2021","02 04 2021","02 10 2021","02 11 2021","02 17 2021","02 18 2021","02 24 2021","02 25 2021"]}
"""
```

In any of the cases the option `.allowFragments` is pointless

---

**Edit**: To repair the rotten JSON replace

```
let data = string.data(using: .utf8)!
```

with

```
let data = Data(str.replacingOccurrences(of: "\"[", with: "[").replacingOccurrences(of: "]\"", with: "]").utf8)
```

or

```
let data = Data(str.replacingOccurrences(of: #""["#, with: "[").replacingOccurrences(of: #"]""#, with: "]").utf8)
```

Comment: Thanks u so much.

Comment: but the string is gotten from api parse. Could you please help me how to replace "[ with [ . Because when i cannot use str.replacingOccurrences(of: "["", with: "[") . because "["" is invalid

Comment: Are you sure, this is exactly the string you get? Create a string from the raw data with `String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)` and print it.

Comment: Yes, this is string is the sample ( also i get from api) in document backend team gives me.

Comment: If there is a *document backend team* tell them to send consistent data. And **never** send a (nested) JSON string as a dictionary value. Replacing characters can't be a solution

Comment: Due to some issues, they cann't fix it now. And i have to manually fix it. And with string you suggest me above, i need to replace "[ with [ . Afterthat, i can continue parsing it :(

Comment: You have also to replace `]"` with `]` on the other side. See the edit.

Comment: Yes, of course. But i don't know how to process it str.replacingOccurrences(of: "["", with: "[") . because "["" is invalid and i get error syntax with complier if i use ""[" or "]"". Could you show me how to do? Thanks so much

Comment: Didn't you notice the **Edit** in the answer?

Comment: ah. Okay. I'm so stupid :D. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

This is the correct format,

```
{
  "01-2021":[
    "01 06 2021",
    "01 07 2021",
    "01 13 2021",
    "01 14 2021",
    "01 20 2021",
    "01 21 2021",
    "01 27 2021",
    "01 28 2021"
  ],
  "02-2021":[
    "02 03 2021",
    "02 04 2021",
    "02 10 2021",
    "02 11 2021",
    "02 17 2021",
    "02 18 2021",
    "02 24 2021",
    "02 25 2021"
  ]
}
```

Oh if you want to check if json is in correct format , you can visit this link
https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/#

Comment: THanks. Just because i get this string from api. And i need to correct it to parse to a Dictionary